# While Loop Seems Endless

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I have a table named `getinvolved` and in this table there are various fields and values, obviously. One such is named `The Route` and contains text separated by commas. For the sake of this we'll say they are `Spot 1, Spot 2, Spot`. Yes the spaces matter.

Now, in my code I first break this value up into an array based on the commas: `$route = explode(",", $row['Content']);` Content is the name of the row that contains the `Spot 1, Spot 2, Spot` text value. This all works fine, I have echo'd this and it appears perfectly.

Next comes the tricky bit, I have multiple other entries that are instead of being labelled `The Route` are instead labelled `Route`. This is an entry for each possible spot, while the current route is `Spot 1, Spot 2, Spot` it could always change to `Spot 2, Spot 1, Tops`.

Each possible entry has it's own row: `Name, Type, Content`. `Type` is where `Route` is set, `Name` is the name of the spot, and `Content` contains a Google Maps URL to show the spot in Google Maps Street View.

What I'm trying to do is take my array `$route[]` which currently contains `Spot 1, Spot 2, Spot` and check those values against all others. I've created a separate array `$echoroute[]` and this contains the actual route with all the information.

My code is as follows:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM getinvolved WHERE Type='Route'");
$echoroute = array_fill(0,count($route),""); #Gives $echoroute[] 3 empty elements as $route will always contain 3 elements at the moment.
$i = 0;
$max = count($route);

if($sql)
{
    foreach($route as $ii)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            if($row['Name'] == $ii)
            {
                $echoroute[$i] = "<a href='" . $row['Content'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['Name'] . "</a> --> ";
                echo $i . " / " . $max . "<br />";
                $i+=1;
                if($i==($max)) {break 2;} else {break 1;}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unable to figure out why but at present during running this code all that happens is it will go through the `if` as `$sql` passes, it enters the first and second `while` loops and then gets to the `if($row['Name'] == $route[$i])` part. Here it seems to work fine until it actually enters the `if` statement (the value in `$row['Name']` is equal to the one in `$route[$i]`).

`$total` is increased as where I ask it to echo it does, but only once. The code ends and displays the following:

```
0 / 3
3
```

- The `1` represents the `$total` variable, which should go through 3 times according to `while($total<$max)`.
- The `/` is me adding a separator for ease of reading.
- The `3` is the `$max` variable, or `count($route)`, the total number of spots included in the `$route` array.
- And finally the trailing `3` is a `count()` function of `$echoroute` letting me know there are 3 elements in that array.

Ultimately, my question is, why does `$total` never get to 2 and finish the loop as I would require?

This took a while to write, so I hope you understand I've put a bit of thought into this, I wrote this a while ago, and it needs some updating and this is where I am currently at.

EDIT:
Have narrowed this down now! Using several echo functions, it appears that the last run through starts, but only makes it as far as the while statement. It never actually enters the while statement. Currently I have two results echo'd and the last result just so happens to be at the bottom of the table. It's the last one to be used before the while($row = statement ends of it's own accord. Am I trapping the while statement or do I need to release it or something? I'm really confused and so close to having the final piece!

Comment: Should if(sql) be if($sql)?

Comment: Your $total is inside the nested while and inside of condition. If second while's condition does less iterations than $max, it will never end. I think you can refactor the loop like `while(cond1 || cond2)` instead of nested loops

Comment: @user2784898 Sorry my mistake, it is already set to $sql :)

Comment: @Royal Bg - I think I understand what you mean, but I've switched the second `while` loop to an `if` statement and I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @user2195574, to how many `$route[$i]` do you expect your `$row['Name']` is equal? You know that `$route = array(0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c')` will have `count($route) = 3` but maximum key "2". So `$route[$i]` will break on the last key, which is 1 keys less than its `count()`, which is still less than $max and the while returns true, so it never breaks

Comment: @user2195574 Do you get any error on the screen? Does it get blank? Any error logged?

Comment: @Ander2 I get no errors, I do get echo'd code and as I said below I now only get 0/3 and the loop stops.

Comment: @user2195574 the it is not entering the if. Put an echo in the while loop and see how much rows are you getting from the DB.

Comment: @Ander2 I added an echo and it returned 5 results, of which there are only 5 it should be receiving and so that is correct.

Comment: Couldn't you just restrict your query to something like: `$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM getinvolved WHERE Type='Route' AND Name IN ('" . implode("','",$route) . "')");`

Comment: @Smorko How would I sort the results from that? The idea is that the results are sorted in the order they have been written. So it takes `Spot 1` and adds that first, then `Spot 2` etc.

Comment: Just to update, I've changed the original post to reflect my code at present.

Comment: I've added an echo where the `if` statement checks if `$total` is equal to `$max` and the echo never gets executed. This means there is a problem somewhere else?

Comment: Have adjusted code once more, I am now getting two results but not the third!

Comment: Have narrowed this down now! Using several echo functions, it appears that the last run through starts, but only makes it as far as the `while` statement. It never actually enters the `while` statement. Currently I have two results echo'd and the last result just so happens to be at the bottom of the table. It's the last one to be used before the `while($row =` statement ends of it's own accord. Am I trapping the `while` statement or do I need to release it or something? I'm really confused and so close to having the final piece!

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `$echoroute` with `count($route)` elements (3 in your example).

You loop over a condition and increase value of `$i` and `$total` if a condition is met.

At this point, into the while loop where `$total` and `$i` values are `2` ( while condition is met 2 < 3 ) and if they enter the `if` condition you get `3` value for `$i` and `$total` and if you `echo $echoroute[$i]` then you've got an error, because `$echoroute` is a 3 element array and you are pointing to a fourth element (remember array indices start from 0 ).

I think this is why you are not getting you expected output.

Comment: I don't understand why `$total` doesn't get echo'd but can be increased? The only place that `$total` is increased has the echo statement follow. It should echo 2 / 3 3 below the already echo'd 1 / 3 3 shouldn't it?

Comment: it should echo each iteration, so you have to have 0/3, 1/3, 2/3 echo'd

Comment: @RoyalBg It should echo only "1/3" and "2/3" in the third one, the error comes and it should break. I supose the error makes the second echo not to show correctly on the screen

Comment: You are right, it never echo's the 0 key, because of incrementing before echo

Comment: I have changed the code to echo prior to increment and I am now only getting 0/3, it goes no further.

Answer (score 0):

i'd write it this way, since there is chance (following Moor laws) that the loop on $total never ends

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM getinvolved WHERE Type='Route'");
$echoroute = array_fill(0,count($route),""); #Gives $echoroute[] 3 empty elements as $route will always contain 3 elements at the moment.
$i = 0;
$total = 0;
$max = count($route);

if($sql)
{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            if($row['Name'] == $route[$i])
            {
                $echoroute[$i] = "<a href='" . $row['Content'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['Name'] . "</a> --> ";
                $i++;
                $total++;
                if ($total>$max) break;
                echo $total . " / " . $max . "<br />" . $echoroute[$i] . count($echoroute);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have adapted this solution as it seems to work best however, I am still not getting anything passed the first run through.